# How to check the model's parameters number in chainer

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, chainer

How to check my chainer model's parameters number? Is it something similar to `model.count_params()` in `Keras`.

Comment: Hi Eric, welcome to SO! You might find it useful to include the results of your own research as well. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the values in the parameters then you can use this

```
# model.params gives you a generator object which you could iterate and see
for i in model.params():
  print(i)
```

If you want to see the names of the layers and shapes then you can use this

```
for i in model.links():
  print(i)
```

If you haven't initialized the input then you can only inspect the biases which are based on per unit. like this

```
total = 0
for idx, i in enumerate(model.params()):
  if idx%2 != 0: # Skipping the weights and looking at biases
    total += len(i)

print(total)
```

In case you have defined your inputs then the weights will not be `None` and you can compute its values as well with slight modifications like this

```
total = 0
for idx, i in enumerate(model.params()):
  if idx%2 != 0:
    total += len(i)
  else:
    total += len(i)*len(i[0]) # len inputs * len units

print(total)

'''
Now for different models, there are different methods so we can use try-except to make it better but be careful as the results might be wrong in some cases. usually, they will be correct. There might be cases when you have nested layers in the model and you have to check recursively.
'''

total = 0
for idx, i in enumerate(model.params()):
  try:
    try:
       total += len(i)
    except:
       total += len(i)*len(i[0])

  except:
       pass
```

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for answering my question.
This code let me check the value of each parameters.
But I want to check the total number of the parameters not the value of parameters.
Is there any solution?

Comment: I load the pretrained model, then I immediately used the forth code.
But I got the following error:
TypeError: len() of unsized object
I found that len(i[0]) caused that error.
Is there any solution or I do anything wrong?

Comment: @EricHong just inspect your model using the first set of code in my answer for your model after that you will know which object you can use `len` upon. If you want to get a complete answer then you have to post your model.

Comment: Hello,
I print my model's i[0] by  the first set of code and got a variable.
I'm not sure why  `len([0]) ` doesn't work.
And I'm not sure what you mean I  have to post my model.
Again, Thanks for replying.

Comment: @EricHong I mean post your model class. The code of your model.

Comment: The model is a little big. You mean directly post the whole code?

Comment: Yes. or you can share its Github link. Anything works.

Comment: I use the model on https://github.com/hitachi-speech/EEND/blob/master/eend/chainer_backend/models.py#L409
line 409~513

Comment: @EricHong I mean your code where you define the model.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Here is my code:https://gist.github.com/erichong0318/bdb2b69adb9034aa4d503796f4f4a4ce

Comment: I can already hear some people shouting at me but still. Just use `try` and `except`. I have edited the code.